# WinError2 Problems opening a LabVIEW program

Tags: python, user-interface, subprocess, call, labview

I'm trying to open a .vi (LabVIEW program) using python.

```
# Allowing access for multiple users
user = input("Username: ")
guiboi = "C:/Users/{}/path_to_folder_containing_gui/name_of_gui.vi".format(user)

## Opening GUI
subprocess.call(['open',guiboi])
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And what happens? Do you have some errors? If so - please post them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that LabVIEW VIs can only be loaded by LV IDE or Run-Time Engine. LabVIEW offers command line interface (`LabVIEWCLI`). One of the canned operations is to programmatically open an arbitrary VI (`RunVI`). Perhaps You can use LV cli and bind it with your python scripts.

```
LabVIEWCLI -OperationName RunVI -VIPath <VI path> <first element of array> <second element of array>
```

Links:
[LabVIEW CLI](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvhowto/cli_running_operations/)
[Canned CLI operations](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvconcepts/cli_predefined_operations/)